# set up a variable in header file using a value from argv

Tags: c, bash, makefile

I need to run many times a code of mine, changing a variable defined in an header file.

I wanted to write a bash script that compiles (through makefile) and runs

```
./myprogram some_value
```

is there a way to use what I recover from atof(argv[1]) inside an header I'm including inside myprogram.c ? (An header shared between many other files, containing the values for the parameters I'm using in my code)

In that header I'd have something like

```
float the_parameter;
```

that I want to initialize to atof(argv[1])

Comment: Is `the_parameter =  atof(argv[1]);` in the `main` function not what you're looking for?

Comment: I'd like it to be in an header so that it's already included in the many files of the project

Comment: The very name `the_parameter` suggests this thing shouldn't be a global in the first place, much less one declared *and* defined in a header file.

Comment: If you need to run the program with a lot of different values for the_parameter, it seems quite counter productive to have it in a header file. Passing it as an argument to the application seems more appropriate.

Comment: Note that `atof` will simply return `0.0` if `argv[1]` does not contain a valid number, for example `57H3evT`. If the input should be checked whether it is a valid number, then using the function [`strtof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) would be better.

Comment: You can't assign this *in the header*, because the arguments passed to _main_  are not available at this point. But since you are willing to **recompile** your program for just this purpose (which sounds pretty bizarre for me), wouldn't it make more sense to use a preprocessor macro instead, which you can set during compilation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, put a declaration of the variable with `extern` in your header file.

```
extern float the_parameter;
```

Then, in *one of* your source file, declare the variable without `extern` and initialize that.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

float the_parameter;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) the_parameter = atof(argv[1]);

    /* other code */
}
```

Comment: I was trying to declare the variable inside main() instead of outside. You solved my problem, thanks a lot. I'll have to study more about external variables